# Как преобразовать Object в Integer для нахождения минимума и максимума

Tags: java, массивы, swing

мне нужно найти минимальное и максимальное значение. Видел способы для нахождения `min` и `max` только для объектов типа `List <Integer>`. Созрел вопрос: как преобразовать `Object` в `Integer`? Пробовала так, но не знаю правильно ли это:

```
  List <Integer> minimum = new ArrayList(listValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос "Как преобразовать Object в Integer", знаю 2 способа:

1. `int intValue = Integer.parseInt(object.toString());`
2. `int intValue = (Integer) object;`

Однако стоит иметь в виду, что на месте Object может быть как число, так и иные символы. Стоит сделать дополнительную проверку на соответствие числу.

Вот возможная реализация с помощью потоков данных (Stream API):

```
    List<Object> listValue = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,2,4,"8a2 ","go",'a',8));
    int minimum = listValue.stream()
            .filter(e -> e instanceof Number)
            .mapToInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.toString()))
            .min()
            .getAsInt();

    System.out.println(minimum);
```

Comment: а если у меня уже объявлен слушатель ActionListener e? И в данном случае у меня подчёркивает e, как мне быть?

Comment: @Valentina e - локальная переменная, просто замените любым другим словом или буквой. Вы так же можете не использовать потоки данных, а применить обычный цикл и прописать всё вручную.

Comment: Мне нужно использовать только такое значение List. Когда ввожу Ваш код, компилятор выдаёт ошибку: no value present

Comment: @Valentina помню в своё время тоже долго пытался написать приложение с применением Swing и всё так же искал решение на просторах стака)) Я так понимаю, у вас примерно такая же ситуация. Хочу порекомендовать вам портал JavaRush, а после, чтение книг. Таких как Java Methods Programming или Философия Java от Брюса Эккеля. И всё станет просто как дважды два)

Comment: @Митяй этот код не совсем корректный. Arrays.asList(5,2,4,"8a2 ","go",'a',8) - отлично работает, другое дело Arrays.asList(5,2,4,"8a2 ","go",'a', "8"). Здесь восьмерка уже не инстанс Number, хотя ее вполне можно спарсить методом Integer.parseInt(). посему в этом случае я бы выносил в приватный метод парсер интеджеров с обработкой нулевых значений и трай-кетч блоком.